# Display:flex or height:auto not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Why doesn't a div that has the style of display:flex or height:auto extend the div to the bottom of the page? Especially when the parent divs are set to height:100%?

I am providing a very specific example to demonstrate this:

http://jsfiddle.net/p1fxh128/1/

```
<div style="height:100vh">
  <section style="height:100vh">
        Welcome...red div below should fill entire container        

            <section style="display:flex; flex-direction: column; background:red; height: auto">
              <header>
                Red Header Here...
              </header>
              <div>
                Red Body here...
              </div>
              <footer>
                Red Footer here...
              </footer>
            </section>

        Random stuff below should still be displayed

    </section>
</div>
```

Notice the red div in this example. Why is it not filling the grid vertically?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dislay flex and auto height (100%) inside](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24701109/dislay-flex-and-auto-height-100-inside)

Comment: use css  'height: 100vh;' on the element.

Comment: not a duplicate of that, since that one indicates that it works on other browsers, but my bootply example does not work in other browsers...

Comment: 100vh doesn't work because I have other items above and below. Plus, the page is too complex to use viewport calc. You'll notice in the bootply example, if you put 100vh, then the "bottom" text does not appear by default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you mean that the red section should take the **remainder** of the page *not* be 100% of the page itself.

That being the case.

```css
* {
    -webkit-background-origin:;
    background-origin:;
    margin: 0;
}
.wrap {
    height:100vh;
}
.wrap > section {
    height:100vh;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.wrap > section > section {
    background:red;
    flex:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <section>Welcome...red div below should fill entire container
        <section>
            <header>Red Header Here...</header>
            <div>Red Body here...</div>
            <footer>Red Footer here...</footer>
        </section>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sit perferendis fugit, ducimus veniam voluptates debitis. Voluptas, recusandae impedit numquam obcaecati accusamus consequuntur, illo fuga ea enim quod facere, repellat tempore!</section>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you - this solved my problem! I am also providing a jsfiddle for the tweaks I made to your solution to provide exactly what I needed. http://jsfiddle.net/2frgt5pd/1/

Answer (score 0):

"Notice the red div in this example." I'm assuming by this you mean the `section` with the red background.

Here's my fork of your jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/lbispo/3u5rkysk/

I removed your inline styles and added this:

```
html, body, body > div, body > div > section { height: 100%; }
body > div > section { display: flex; flex-direction: column; }
body > div > section > section { flex: 1; background-color: red; }
```

The selectors would be simpler with the ids and classes you had in your previous example. `height: 100%` added to `html` and `body`, and changed selectors for the flexbox, adding `flex: 1` to the stretchy element.

Hope this helps. My first answer!

Comment: It seems like this takes up >100% vertically though, because a scrollbar appears, and the bottom text is cut off.